# Save powerpoint macro does not run

Tags: vba, ms-word, powerpoint

I have problem with the macro VBA macro. It did work, but now is does not work anymore. Does anybody have a clue what might go wrong?

```
 Sub SaveName()

Dim i As Integer
Dim pptcount As Integer

Dim pptapp As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim pres As Presentations
Dim var1 As String

Set pptapp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
pptapp.Visible = True


Set pres = Application.Presentations(i)
var1 = InputBox("geef hier je maand aan")


pptcount = Application.Presentations.Count

For i = 1 To pptcount

    Application.ActivePresentation.SaveAs "X:\SSC_HR\SENS\Bedrijfsbureau\Rapportages\SENS referenten rapportage\Template_Uploaden\" & "var1" & ".ppt"

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: do you get any error? if so, what is error description? in which line?...

Comment: I get a complile error saying "method or data member not found

Comment: Please always include the exact text of the error and tell us what line the error occurs on.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead, see comments:

```
Sub SaveName()

' VBA will convert this stuff for you
' but internally they're longs
' May as well dim them correctly to start with
Dim i As Long
Dim pptcount As Long

' Dim this as Application, not as presentation:
Dim pptapp As PowerPoint.Application

Dim pres As Presentation
Dim var1 As String

Set pptapp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
pptapp.Visible = True


Set pres = Application.Presentations(i)
var1 = InputBox("geef hier je maand aan")


pptcount = Application.Presentations.Count

For i = 1 To pptcount

    Application.ActivePresentation.SaveAs "X:\SSC_HR\SENS\Bedrijfsbureau\Rapportages\SENS referenten rapportage\Template_Uploaden\" & "var1" & ".ppt"

Next

End Sub
```

I haven't run it, but at least it compiles now.  ;-)

Comment: Hmm, tried to run it Steve but still get the same error. Do you have any idea what might cause the fact that I receive an error and you dont? Am using office 2003 by the way (dont know if might influence anything...)

Answer (score 0):

Steve said he didn't RUN it there are several errors and it's not at all clear what it should do.
Not an error but probably not needed

Set pptapp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")

pptapp.Visible = True

ERROR
Set pres = Application.Presentations(i) 'i is zero so it will fail

ERRORS
This is saving the same presentation several times and var1 should NOT be in ""
For i = 1 To pptcount
Application.ActivePresentation.SaveAs "X:\SSC_HR\SENS\Bedrijfsbureau\Rapportages\SENS referenten rapportage\Template_Uploaden\" & "var1" & ".ppt"
Next